# How can I download file inside a folder in Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am using an https triggered Google Cloud Function that is supposed to download a file from Google Cloud Storage (and then combine it with data from req.body). While it seems to work as long as the downloaded file is in the root directory I am having problems accessing the same file when placed inside a folder. The path to the file is `documents/someTemplate.docx`

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require('path');
const os = require("os");
const fs = require('fs');
const gcconfig = {
  projectId: "MYPROJECTNAME",
  keyFilename: "KEYNAME.json"
};
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')(gcconfig)
const bucketPath = 'MYPROJECTNAME.appspot.com'
const bucket = Storage.bucket(bucketPath);

exports.getFileFromStorage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      let fileName = 'documents/someTemplate.docx'
      let tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

      return bucket.file(fileName)
      .download({
          destination: tempFilePath,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(fileName + ' downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
          let content = fs.readFileSync(tempFilePath, 'binary');

          // do stuff with the file and data from req.body

          return
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: err
          });
        });
})
```

What I don't understand is that when I move the file to the root directory and use the file name `someTemplate.docx` instead then the code works.

[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console) states that

> Objects added to a folder appear to reside within the folder in the GCP Console. In reality, all objects exist at the bucket level, and simply include the directory structure in their name. For example, if you create a folder named pets and add a file cat.jpeg to that folder, the GCP Console makes the file appear to exist in the folder. In reality, there is no separate folder entity: the file simply exists in the bucket and has the name pets/cat.jpeg.

This seems to be correct as in the metadata the file name is indeed `documents/someTemplate.docx`. Therefore I don't understand why the code above does not work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Is there an error message?

Comment: use `firebase serve --only functions` to run locally so you can get console errors (faster).

Comment: Also, perhaps the directory doesn't exist on the temp folder location?  Maybe try `let tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tempkjhgfhjnmbvgh.docx');`

Comment: @JamesPoag Thanks, that was the problem, I didn't realize that it doesn't create a folder automatically. Strangely, I never got an error message even though I did use `firebase serve` the entire time. It would tell me e.g `Execution took 16 ms, user function completed successfully` but neither run the `then` nor `catch` part.

Comment: I think a lot of people use the `tmp` node module: `npm install tmp`

Comment: @JamesPoag, may you post your good answer as an answer in order to be accepted and help other users to find it easily?

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment answer from @James Poag for visibility:

Also, perhaps the directory doesn't exist on the temp folder location? Maybe try let `tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tempkjhgfhjnmbvgh.docx');` – James Poag Aug 21 at 17:10